# get $this->getUser() in FormType Symfony4

Tags: symfony4

I have a Entity called Profile, with a relationship to Category. Both are scoped by company_id.

When I create a new Profile, I want to show possible categories from my company_id only.

CategoryRepository has the following method:

```
/**
    * @return Category[] Returns an array of Category objects
    */
    public function findByCompany($value)
    {
        dump($value);
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.company = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

The method works correctly when used from category index, where it lists my company categories.

But, not, in creating a profile, I need to get the relationship.

ProfileType form is as follows:

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('type')
    ->add('serial')
    ->add('sgin')
    ->add('sensor', EntityType::class, [
        'class'=>'App\Entity\Sensor',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
    ])
    ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
        'class'=>'App\Entity\Category',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function (CategoryRepository $er) use($user) {
            return $er->findByCompany($user);
        },
    ])
```

as far as I can tell, the $user here should hold $this->getuser() (because from it I can call getCompany), or pass the whole company entity. Passing an ID itself doesn't seem to work, I tried doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller set an option in your `createForm()` funtion to get your user's ID:

```
'userId' => $this->getUser()->getId()
```

Then, in ProfileType.php in your `buildform()` function above `$builder->add(...)` get the user through the option you set in the controller like this:

```
$userId = $options['userId'];
```

Comment: I have read something like that, so its progress... but...my controller passes the $profile object, which seems is required. I did add the Company object to it... but could not access it. ```
   $profile->setCompany($this->getUser()->getCompany());
   $form = $this->createForm(ProfileType::class, $profile);

Comment: This is my most latest attemp... the company variable does get the object, but I can't pass it to the repository, generates an error.  `$company=$options['data']->getCompany();
        $builder->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class'=>'App\Entity\Category',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'query_builder' => function (CategoryRepository $er) use($company) {
                    return $er->findByCompany($company);
                },
            ]);`

Comment: @TDawg, in that case you have to query in your formfield on the company id in that case, not the whole object. In your controller, get the company, and pass only the id to the formType. using the option (see optionsresolver in the docs). Then in your formType you can use this value for your query.

Comment: Solved. I tried something similar to your way, and it worked... but needed a few changes.  1) I passed the company object as I did in my first reply to you 2) passed the options to query_builder 3) the repository needed to return a QueryBuilder rather than a reult, so I changed the query (needed a second one for the main page). Not sure if that makes sense, but it works. I'll accept your answer as you put on the path

Comment: Not completely sure what you did to make it work, but i'm glad you figured it out ;)